# What is the plural for the abbreviation of the word "captain"?

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations, military

I thought it would be Cpts., as in: "Captains Johansson and Riley were present" -> "Cpts. Johansson and Riley were present", but I cannot find anything definitive online.

Additionally, I would have just used Cpts., except I'm finding lots of results saying CPT should be capitalised, and/or should use Capt (or possibly Capt.) instead. So then I'm wondering if CPTs or CPTS would be the proper usage?

(This is in a purely military usage. And I suspect another issue is based on the country and branch being discussed. I have no specific branch intended. I am American but tend to use British English quite often.)

Comment: CPT as an abbreviation is neither an acronym nor, really, an initialism. Most guidelines target these subsets. However, as CPT looks very like an initialism, it's probably best to assume a similar convention, resulting in CPTs rather than CPTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, the abbreviation of captain depends on the branch of service (in the US). The plural, then, is created by adding a lower-case 's'.

However, it appears that the plural 'capts.' - especially as used in British English - is archaic. You can find references in 19th century issues of the [Asiatic Journal](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2ZY3AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA616&dq=%22capts.%22#v=onepage&q=%22capts.%22&f=false), for example; also note the title of a 1804-6 travelogue of Lewis and Clark ([The Travels of Capts. Lewis and Clarke from St. Louis,...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=plVXf-6_3dAC))

Here is a usage of 'CPTs' in modern American ([*Armor*, volume 111, issue 5](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VTopUWn9-YkC&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

In conclusion, if you must abbreviate, I suspect you should use the pluralised form for the service branch you refer to. Or just use 'capts.' for a bit of that old je ne sais quoi.